# Unable to load Perl subpackage

Tags: perl, perl-module

I can't work out why I am unable to access a subpackage:

`mbzdb`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use lib "./lib";
use MbzDb::Instance;

my $instance = new MbzDb::Instance();
$instance->startFromCommandLine();
```

`lib/MbzDb/Instance.pm`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

package MbzDb::Instance;

use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;
require Exporter;
our @ISA = qw(Exporter);
our @EXPORT = qw(new startFromCommandLine);

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    return bless {}, $class;
}

sub startFromCommandLine {
    my $self = shift;
}
```

If I use the same code in `lib/MbzDb.pm` the export works correctly. What am I doing wrong?

The error given is:

> Can't locate object method "new" via package "MbzDb::Instance" (perhaps you forgot to load "MbzDb::Instance"?) at ./mbzdb line 6.

Comment: Does the same code work in lib/Mbzdb.pm if you comment out the use lib?

Comment: If I remove `use lib "./lib";` then it is unable to find the module. If I remove it and move the `.pm`s to another location I get the same error.

Comment: Hmmm, and there isn't another lib directory under MbzDb (i.e. lib/Mbzdb/lib ?

Comment: No, there is no other directories.

Comment: perl v5.10.1 on Ubuntu 10.04 this code does not give the reported error.  If the directories were wrong then the "use" line would report the error not the "new" line

Comment: just to restate that- on my version of perl there is no error, the code given works

Comment: Just in case.. Do you have `return 1` at end of `MbzDb::Instance` module? And another note: exporting `new` can lead to big bugs, i dont think you need to export it

Comment: This was my fault, the text editor was holding onto a bad file :(

Comment: @ElliotChance, no problem, but please close the question so that no one else tries to solve it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the excellent [FindBin](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.16.3/lib/FindBin.pm) module.

```
use FindBin;
use lib $FindBin::Bin . '/lib';
use MbzDb::Instance;
```

This works if your structure looks like this:

```
mbzdb
lib/
  MbzDb/
    Instance.pm
```